# How to separate two data exists in one field at database

Tags: php

Lets say I have field at my table in MySQL database which is called `product_colors`.

Now in this field I have inserted this value:

`#000,#fff`

Then within PHP, I tried to get this data into variable:

```
$pro_colors = $row_results['product_colors'];
```

So `$pro_colors` contains this as result:

`#000,#fff`

Now what I want to do is to separate each color by this

> ,

sign so `#000` would be assigned a different variable and `#fff` also would be assigned to another variable.

So if you know how to do this with PHP, please let me know... Thanks!

**Note:** I have skipped writing other unnecessary codes for retrieving data from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, like so:

```
$pro_colors = explode(',', $row_results['product_colors']);
```

The first parameter is the delimiter, which in your case is `,`. The second parameter is your string. The function returns an array of strings, so `$pro_colors[0]` will be `#000` and `$pro_colors[1]` will be `#fff`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "explode" function as follows

```
$splitStringArray = explode(",", $pro_colors);
```

The PHP manual for explode can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php